# Отлов изменений свойств сервиса в компонентах Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Всем привет, прошу помочь мне разобраться в чем проблема. Изучаю ангуляр и споткнулся на обсерверах.

Ситуация: 
Есть сервис, который отправляет запрос getWeather() и полученный ответ назначает свойству weatherCatalog. Но для правильного формирования урла ему требуется сначала определить координаты пользователя с помощью методов setUrl() и setPosition();

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
    key = 'dd6301427900459c863160646190201';
    weatherCatalog;
    queryString = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setUrl(position) {
    this.queryString = `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=${this.key}&q=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&num_of_days=14&tp=4&format=json`;

    this.getWeather()
  }

  getWeather() {
    this.http.get(this.queryString)
        .subscribe(
            res => this.weatherCatalog = res,
            err => console.error(err)
        );
  }

  setPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setUrl.bind(this))
  }
}
```

Есть компонент где я пытаюсь скопировать полученный по запросу сервиса обьект в свойство компонента weather. Но разумеется ничего не получается, т.к видимо на момент назначения, свойство сервиса weatherCatalog является undefined

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.scss']
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  weather;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
    this.weather = weatherService.weatherCatalog
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.weatherService.setPosition();
  }

}
```

Задумка же выглядела так - я получаю координаты пользователя, после чего отправляю запрос на сервер, полученный ответ записываю в свойство и это свойство передаю компоненту, где копирую его в собственное свойство. Буду благодарен если подскажете как можно это реализовать или что прочитать на эту тему.

Comment: я так и не понял в чем заключается ваш вопрос? с чем вы столкнулись/что работает/не работает/какие-то ошибки/что угодно?

Comment: свойство weather у компонента в этом моменте:
this.weather = weatherService.weatherCatalog
получает значение undefined, а после того как в сервисе свойству weatherCatalog назначается объект полученный из запроса, значения свойства weather компонента не изменяется. Вопрос в том, как можно реализовать это используя средства rxjs

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что он должен получить значение если оно сеттится через N промежуток времени? ваш вопрос заключается в том как получить свойство `weatherCatalog` в компоненте `CurrentWeatherComponent`?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы синхронно пытаетесь работать с асинхронным кодом.

Давайте перепишем `WeatherService` следующим образом:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WeatherService {
  private key = 'dd6301427900459c863160646190201';

  private queryString = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private getCurrentPosition(): Observable<Position> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      // `getCurrentPosition` - асинхронная функция, для удобства оборачиваем в поток
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: Position) => {
        observer.next(position);
        observer.complete();
      }, (error) => {
        observer.error(error);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  private setQueryString(position: Position): void {
    this.queryString = `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=${this.key}&q=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&num_of_days=14&tp=4&format=json`;
  }

  private getWeather() {
    return this.http.get(this.queryString);
  }

  public getWeatherCatalog() {
    // получили `Position`
    return this.getCurrentPosition().pipe(
      // засеттили `queryString`
      tap((position) => this.setQueryString(position)),
      // делаем запрос на этот `queryString`
      switchMap(() => this.getWeather())
    );
  }
}
```

Внутри компонента вам не нужно пытаться достучаться до свойства `weatherCatalog`, так как вы никогда не получить его синхронным образом, будем получать каталог погоды следующим образом:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.scss']
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent {
  public weather = null;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherCatalog().subscribe((weather) => {
      this.weather = weather;
      console.log(this.weather);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это именно то, что было нужно. Пойду изучать работу обсерверов)